# Remove underscores from filename

Tags: currfile, underscore

I am using currfile package to get the file name. 
My file name has the form

"code blah blah blah.tex"

what is being displayed is

"code_blah_blah_blah.tex"

How can I remove the underscores?

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[twoside,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{currfile}

\newcommand{\fileName}{\currfilebase}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\fileName}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
  Test
\end{document}
```

Here is the output

[image: Output]

Comment: An example, please.

Comment: is it really an underscore or the verbatim visible space character (which has short uprights at either end)

Comment: There are no underscores in my output: http://i.imgur.com/MQXAxTP.png

Comment: It is an actual underscore.

Comment: No, there is not. At least not in the output on my machine. Did you clicked the link I gave you above? Where do you see the underscores? Even copying the text from pdf reveal no underscore. Please show us the output on your machine (edit your question and add it there).

Comment: What operating system and TeX distribution are you on?

Comment: alwaysask I saw your output, that is what I want. I am on Windows 7 using MikTex.

Comment: You can't get the output you showed with the MWE you posted (where STP Competency and that file name came from??). Please use the **exact** MWE you posted, save the file as `code blah blah blah.tex` (without underscores), then compile the MWE and post the result. That is for all of us to speak the same language.

Comment: Output as in MWE.

Comment: 1) Did you make sure the actual file name on the disk is without underscores? 2) Is your Miktex up do date?

Comment: Miktex is up to date and file name has no underscores.

Comment: texlive returns the filename surrounded by quotes if there are spaces, so I can not reproduce. Can you add `\typeout{JOBNAME=\jobname}` to your document, and show the log output from that, I get `JOBNAME="aaa bbb ccc"` from a file called `aaa bbb ccc.tex`

Comment: Still appears with underscores.

Comment: Ok, if I use LuaLatex instead of pdfLatex the underscores go but I have quotation marks, how do I get rid of them?

Comment: [Crosspost](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=27526&view=unread&sid=2e423278582f7fe4bdd040c682d64cfe#unread)

Answer (score 1):

This MWE works for me:

```
\documentclass[twoside,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 %\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
{hyperref}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\fileName}{\currfilebase}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\StrSubstitute{\fileName}{"}{}}

\begin{document}
    Test
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]